# How to use ngIf to check if another element exists?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How do I condition an element to show/hide if another element (which will be dynamically populated at a later time) exists?

For example:

`app.component.ts`

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {

         //Run a library that will populate the table, for example
         //This will create an element with an id tableData
         generateTableDataAfterDOMIsReady('#container');

    }

}
```

`app.component.html`

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- When the javascript function is invoked, it will dynamically change the content inside this div and generate a <div id="tableData"></div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="pseudoIsTableDataExists()">Data has been generated</div>
```

There is no other variable I can listen to in order to make it work. The sole clue is to condition the second `div` to show itself when #tableData exists.

Comment: You can check for the existence of *tableData* using `@ViewChild`. If it is present then it means your function was successful, if not then it failed.

Comment: That sounds great. Would you mind guiding me with some code? :D

Comment: Included an answer.. Let me know your thoughts. `@ViewChild` will work if the tag had id in the form of `#tableData`. Since you have the `id` attribute, we can use plain old JavaScript.

Comment: Hi. I am still trying out each options and figuring out if they work under all the circumstance. I can see one working but I'm still checking on the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the existence of *tableData* by injecting the [Document](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) token into the constructor. Next, use plain old JavaScript to find the element by id. Once the view loads, check if it is present as shown below:

```
import { Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   if (document.getElementById('tableData')) {
      // success scenario
   } else {
      // failure
   }
}

ngOnInit() {
   generateTableDataAfterDOMIsReady('#container');
}
```

Move the call of `generateTableDataAfterDOMIsReady('#container');` to the ngOnInit rather than in the ngAfterViewInit.

*`@ViewChild` would be better but it works only if the id of the tag is specified as `#id`.*

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to set a flag

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {

         //Run a library that will populate the table, for example
         //This will create an element with an id tableData
         generateTableDataAfterDOMIsReady('#container');
         this.pseudoIsTableDataExists=true
    }
```

and

```
<div *ngIf="pseudoIsTableDataExists">Data has been generated</div>
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion but there's no way to check on the success of `generateTableDataAfterDOMIsReady` except for checking for the existence of #tableData. The operation can fail too.

Comment: Check it then and assign the result. KISS

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can bind `hidden` property.

#### HTML

```
<div [hidden]="!isTableDataExists">
    Data has been generated
</div>
```

#### Component

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {

     //Run a library that will populate the table, for example
     //This will create an element with an id tableData
     generateTableDataAfterDOMIsReady('#container');
     this.isTableDataExists = true;
}
```